# Is there a way to detect, through browser Javascript, multi-touch events of a trackpad, magic mouse or magic trackpad on a Mac?

Tags: javascript, macos, dom-events, multi-touch

I know there are many ways to do so directly on the iPhone (jQtouch), but I'd like to detect those events in my computer's browser.

Comment: Would hammer.js help?

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla has some support for mouse gestures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mouse_gesture_events

Looks like chrome and safari don't have native support for the same : [JQuery - Can I query the MacBook Pro Trackpad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677783/jquery-can-i-query-the-macbook-pro-trackpad)