# Multi-touch gestures in webapp on desktop

Tags: javascript, macos, browser, multi-touch, gestures

I'm developing online map(like google maps) of cool fantasy world.  I'm also use OS X on my main computer. Since OS X(especially Lion) are focused on different multi-touch gestures because almost of all mac users have a multi-touch input device(magic mouse or trackpad) I want to add support of pinch gesture to my online map(two-finger scroll would be cool to add too). Is it possible to do it? It's not bad if it will work only in some specific browser or web engine.

Comment: http://scripty2.com/demos/touch/ - it's open source, works on handheld devices (tested on my Android), but doesn't seem to work on desktops (they talk about some fallback techniques, but I have no way to check it).

Comment: Unfortunately (if I'm right) it uses touch API which available only on mobile device with touchscreen.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677783/jquery-can-i-query-the-macbook-pro-trackpad), it looks like firefox offers some support for multitouch gestures (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Mouse_gesture_events)), but other major browsers do not.

Answer (score 1):

recently I've been developing webapplication for iPad using my PC and Chrome, it used a pinch feature. I found a way how to emulate touch and multi-touch feature on a desktop browser, posted my results on github here https://github.com/dgolovanev/mxTouch still does not supports predefined gestures but can handle touch and multi-touch events, hope it will be helpful